# Extract only one file in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, zip

Hello i am trying to extract zip file using

```
System.IO.Compression;
```

and i write the following line to extract the zip file

```
 var storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
            string zipFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(storagePath.AbsolutePath, "AAA.zip");

            String unZipLocation = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile, unZipLocation);
```

it extract the file but the problem is that it extract first file only.

I want to extract full zip

how to overcome that problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string zipDir = @"d:\zip\zipped.zip";
 string extractDir = @"d:\zip\unzippedFiles";
 ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipDir, extractDir);
```

Comment: You need to create new folder

Comment: if there any way to extarct folder dynamically

Comment: Try create folder in: String unZipLocation = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath; and unzip it inside the folder.